# Function keys: won't work with macros (I tried a lot)

Tags: terminal, key-bindings

Specs:

- Vim 8.0 patch 500
- gnome-terminal 3.18.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 running Unity

Function keys in my vim *slightly* misbehave, however, in an annoying way: I can't completely use them in my macros. After much trial and error I have given up and think I need help here. Please? :)

Mapping Function keys works

- `nmap <F2><F2> :echo 'works!'<CR>`
- also works: `nmap <Leader>2 <F2><F2>`

But if I record a macro with function keys in it, it sometimes works, sometimes not. This is what I get when I record a macro with an `<F9>` in it:

- The macro is typed as `"w<F9>p` (put style invocation of something with register `w`)
- replaying the macro however, leads to the invocation of my ex command at the receiving end of the  mapping with `v:register` set to `a`
- Pasting the macro register yields `"w�k9p`, which vim renders as [image: vim rendering of pasted macro register] and which xxd tells me is the byte string `2277 806b 3970`
- Typing `<C-V><F9>` in insert mode yields `^[[20~` and I think that is what vim is also expecting to see when `<F9>` is used in a mapping. It is also what I see when I type `F9` into plain `cat`.

Many of my mappings involve function keys and I want to fix this once and for all. My attempts to date involved the following:

```
nmap ?k9 <F9>
```

where the `?` is the literal pasted `<80>` thingy from before. Upon loading that file again, the bracketed representation did not appear again; however, I have confirmed with xxd that the exact byte representation of the symbol in .vimrc is still `80`.

Another one through the use of

```
set <F9>=^[[20~
```

(inserted literally with `<C-V>` as you'd expect)

To no avail. Please help me so that I can use the F9 key in a macro! thanks!

---

Edit 1:

In GVim, I get the exact same behavior. This means, it is not the fault of my terminal emulator, right?